# How to get jQuery Validate to fire the "success" method "onchange" instead of "onblur" for select menus?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, onchange, onblur

I'm using the jQuery validate plug-in. I am using the `show()` method to display the submit button once there are no errors on the page.

I have a form that just has a single select/drop-down menu. The issue I am running into is when I select an option in the select, it doesn't show the submit button until I click somewhere else on the page, when it should show it as soon as I select a valid option.

Does anyone know how to get it to fire the `success()` `onchange` or `onkeyup` instead of `onblur`?

Here's a basic example of what I'm doing:

```
$form.validate( {
    rules: {
        favoriteSport: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        favoriteSport: "This is required"
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("yay, it was valid!");

        $("#submit").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: you should consider posting some of the code you have tried...

Comment: I just posted some code.

Comment: how do you call the validate function..post that to (HTML code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a separate call to bind() so whenever a change event occurs, it runs $validate() agains the ID of the select menu.

It's hard to believe this isn't built in to the plug-in seeing how it's the most popular form validation plug-in for jQuery.

Here's an example:

```
$("#favoriteSport").bind("change keyup", function() {
    $form.validate().element("#favoriteSport");
});
```

Comment: This is a bit inefficient, I'd like to see someone else answer this so please leave it open for a bit if you don't mind. I agree, there should be an option for this for selects that you don't have to call explicitly. Other fields will validate on keyup. Looking through the docs, there appear to be no options for `<select>` fields... Nice trick though!

Comment: Thanks for the interest and looking into it more. I would also like to see a better solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this `.change()` instead of `.blur()`....

```
$("#idofSelect").change(function(){

  $("#submitButtonID").show()

})
```

Comment: I'm not calling blur(), I'm using jQuery Validate (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) and am using $("form").validate();

Comment: @Cofey: show us some of your code you have done...that might help

Comment: he's using the popular jquery validation plugin, which by default validates fields on blur. He wants to alter the default behavior. Normally you don't manually call the validation methods, so there is probably no code to work with other than the plugin itself.

Comment: @Madmartigan: he can call that method `onchange` of the `select` if there is only one combo-box to validate

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since this question was asked and I still don't believe a native fix to this issue has been provided by the plugin developer. @Cofey you were on the right track and I think a slight improvement to your answer's logic would help to make the solution dynamic for all selects:

```
$('select').bind('change keyup', function() {
    $('form').validate().element(this);
});
```